# AWS (SNS) Platform EndPoint is disabled itself apple device (Not publishing anything)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, endpoint

I was using AWS SNS which was working fine but suddenly it stop working and when I try to publish message from AWS console, it says end point "Endpoint is disabled (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EndpointDisabled; Request ID: 27a183ab-2940-54b0-8ad3-d2c1fd5ba0c0)"

We used different token , assuming that can be a device token issue. But no luck. Can anybody help us to get this resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266922/aws-sns-endpoint-getting-disabled-on-its-own) answer? It seems the problem can happen when:

> 1. GCM and APNS can disable your device's endpoint, based on some cleanup policy. In other words, the devices are subjected to change in their endpoints and is not in control of AWS.
>      When GCM disables your device endpoint, then it create a mapping between the new endpoint and the old endpoint. Using this mapping, it is still able
> 2. to serve notifications via the old endpoint. But, this mapping is there for a short while only. Once, this mapping is gone, the notifications start to fail. Also, while the mapping is there, the GCM provides a warning message to SNS, that the endpoint will soon be disabled and also provides the new endpoint, but it only gets logged.